# Regex that can find lines continued with a comma

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I wish use a regex to be used in `Sublime Text 3`to find commands like

```
get :action, id: 1, name: 'John',
   children: 3
```

My initial attempt is `get :[\w]*,[^\n]*`. This will work if the command is on a single line i.e

```
get :action, id: 5, name: 'Chris'
```

but does not work when the command is written over several lines with a comma continuation. What is the regex that will work with a  multi-line command?

The Sublime Text find operation uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE).

Comment: What regex dialect are you using? There are functionality and syntax differences between them, so that information is highly relevant. Your question now is the equivalent of *I'm traveling to a foreign country tomorrow. How do I say "Where can I find the restroom?"* The answer is going to depend on exactly what language you need to say it in, and without knowing that you're likely to need a new pair of pants.

Comment: Sublime Text 3. I have added this information to the question.

Comment: If you're writing a plugin for Sublime Text 3, you'll be using Python? I think? See http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-basics

Comment: I am just using the search and replace function. It looks like sublime text uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE), http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
get :\w+(?:,\n?[^\n,]+)+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/31eqye/1)

- `get :` literal
- `\w+` one or more word characters
- `(?:` begin sub-expression

  - `,` literal
  - `\n?` an optional newline
  - `[^\n,]+` at least one character that isn't a newline or a comma
- `)+` match this sub-expression at least once